# Not able to get the exact portion cropped image by using OpenGL in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es

In my Ipad app i'm using OpenGL framework to crop the image.I'm not much familier with OpenGL.Here in my app I need to crop some portion of image and display it on an image view. For cropping effect I use OpenGL framework. The cropping effect was working fine but when I am assigning that image to the imageview full black image is getting displayed instead of the cropped image.I'm not getting where I had gone wrong.If any one works on it please guide me and also please post/suggest links which are related to my requirement.

I'm using this code: _sourceImage is the captured image.

```
-(void)showResult
{

   UIImage *imageCrop;
   float scaleCrop;
   if (_sourceImage.size.width >= IMAGEWIDTH)
   {
       scaleCrop = IMAGEWIDTH / _sourceImage.size.width;
       imageCrop = [ImageCropViewController scaleImage:_sourceImage with:CGSizeMake(_sourceImage.size.width*scaleCrop, _sourceImage.size.height*scaleCrop)];
   }
   else
   {
       scaleCrop = 1;
       imageCrop = _sourceImage;

   }

   float scale = _sourceImage.size.width / resizeImage.size.width * 2;
   IplImage *iplImage = [ImageCropViewController CreateIplImageFromUIImage:imageCrop] ;
   Quadrilateral rectan;

   rectan.point[0].x = _touchLayer.rectan.pointA.x*scale*scaleCrop;
   rectan.point[0].y = _touchLayer.rectan.pointA.y*scale*scaleCrop;

   rectan.point[1].x = _touchLayer.rectan.pointB.x*scale*scaleCrop;
   rectan.point[1].y = _touchLayer.rectan.pointB.y*scale*scaleCrop;

   rectan.point[2].x = _touchLayer.rectan.pointC.x*scale*scaleCrop;
   rectan.point[2].y = _touchLayer.rectan.pointC.y*scale*scaleCrop;

   rectan.point[3].x = _touchLayer.rectan.pointD.x*scale*scaleCrop;
   rectan.point[3].y = _touchLayer.rectan.pointD.y*scale*scaleCrop;

   IplImage* dest = cropDoc2(iplImage,rectan);

   IplImage *image = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(dest), IPL_DEPTH_8U, dest->nChannels);
   cvCvtColor(dest, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
   cvReleaseImage(&dest);



   UIImage *tempImage = [ImageCropViewController UIImageFromIplImage:image withImageOrientation:_sourceImage.imageOrientation];
  [self crop:tempImage];
  cvReleaseImage(&image);

}
-(void)crop:(UIImage*)image
{    
   //Adjust the image size, to scale the image to 1013 of width
   float targetWidth = 1000.0f;
   float scale = targetWidth / image.size.width;
   float scaleheight = image.size.height * scale;
   UIImage *imageToSent = [ImageCropViewController scaleImage:image with:CGSizeMake(targetWidth, scaleheight)];
   // Image data with compression
   imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSent,0.75);
   NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
   NSString *caldate = [now description];
   appDelegate.imagefilePath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,caldate];
   [imageData writeToFile:appDelegate.imagefilePath atomically:YES];

   appDelegate.cropimage=imageToSent;


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Black usually means you failed to pull the data out of OpenGL, and you ended up with a blank image.

How are you getting the image back from OpenGL? OpenGL doesn't work with normal images - you have to issued custom OpenGL calls to pull the image in.